# Pandas: dt.dayofweek showing incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dayofweek

I am struggling to understand why the day of week is interpreting a Friday as day of week 4.

Some simple data:

```
import pandas as pd

# Simple time series data:
series = pd.Series({"2017-02-20": 1, '2017-02-21':2, '2017-02-22':3, '2017-02-23': 4, '2017-02-24':5})
datetime = pd.to_datetime(series.index)

# turn series in to dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(series.values, index=datetime)
```

Now if we call `argmax()` and ask what day of week it is we get:

```
df[0].argmax().dayofweek

# 4
```

So it is saying that Friday is day 4 of the week, which is obviously wrong by any standards.

Am I doing something wrong? I have spent far too long on this problem!

I can hazard a guess that this function isn't implemented properly but it sort of defeats the object for me if it can't compute the day of week for any arbitrary datetime index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in the docs for [`DateTimeIndex.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html),

> The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6

So yes, Friday would be labelled as 4. If you don't like this particular mapping of numbers to the days of the week, you could always map this mapping to whatever you prefer, e.g. if you wanted Sunday->Saturday as 1->7,

```
>>> custom_map = dict(zip(range(7), [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]))

>>> custom_map
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 1}
```

although I don't really see the value in doing so.